# Where does Authlite store the second factor?

Tags: active-directory, authentication, u2f

[Authlite](https://www.authlite.com) is an Active Directory extention to use second factors. They seem to have their own partition on a domain controller, and use global groups to manage their users.
So the question is where do they store the second factor information for each user? In an attribute of the user, so they manipulate the schema? In their application partition? Or do they have an extra location for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mentioned in [the documentation](https://www.authlite.com/docs/2_3/id_594072452/):

> AuthLite does not add or change any schema properties on the "user" or other built-in objects in Active Directory. All AuthLite data is stored separately in the AuthLite Application Partition. Adding the AuthLite schema elements will have no performance impact on user object replication since we don't touch those objects at all.